# An example of a function for which the limit exists at some x, but not differentiable at x

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Assume $f$ is differentiable at $x$,

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h} .$$

which can be proven by,

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h} &=& 
\frac12 \lim_{h\to 0}\left(\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h+\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}h\right)
\\ &=& \frac12 (f'(x)+f'(x)) = f'(x)
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

but here's the **real** question,

> Give an example of a function $f(x)$ for which the limit above exists at some $x$, but $f$ is not differentiable at $x$.

I am confused by this question because I originally, thought, by definition of differentiation, existence of limit at some $x$ guarantees differentiability at that 'some' $x$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $x=0$ and make $f$ an even function.  Then we have
$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}=\frac{f(h)-f(-h)}{2h}=0$$
for all $h$ and so
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}=0\ .$$
It remains to find an example where $f$ is not differentiable at $0$.  A somewhat trivial example is
$$f(x)=\cos\frac{1}{x}$$
- this is not differentiable at $0$ because it is not defined at $0$.  (But the limit above **does** exist - think carefully about the definition of limit.)  A more interesting example:
$$f(x)=|x|$$
which is continuous but not differentiable at $0$.  I leave you to check the details.

Comment: couldnt ask for more, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Existence of $\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$ means differentiability at $x$.  But this question is about a different limit.

Hint: try an even function....

Answer (score 1):

The may not be particularly satisfying, but put $f(x) = 0$ for $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=1$. Then the limit exists and is zero at $x=0$ but $f$ isn't even continuous there, much less differentiable.

Comment: $f(x) = \lvert x \rvert$ works as well.

Comment: aaa i was dumb not to think about $x=0$ thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about, $y = x^{2/3}$
evaluated at $0.$

Piece-wise functions are good for these sorts of problems.

$   f\left(x\right) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       x^2 & : x \le 0\\
       x & : x > 0
     \end{array}
   \right.\\$